# Converting SQL query to JPQL

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa

This query was executed on MySQL Employees Sample Database to count all employees from one specific department:

```
select count(*) from (
                SELECT a.* FROM employees.employees a
    INNER JOIN employees.dept_emp b ON a.emp_no = b.emp_no
    INNER JOIN employees.titles c ON a.emp_no = c.emp_no
    WHERE b.dept_no = 'd002'
    GROUP BY a.emp_no
    HAVING MAX(b.to_date) = (SELECT MAX(to_date) FROM employees.dept_emp WHERE emp_no = a.emp_no)
    AND MAX(c.to_date) = (SELECT MAX(to_date) FROM employees.titles WHERE emp_no = a.emp_no) ORDER BY a.emp_no ASC
) AS X;
```

I've tried to convert this to JPQL, but couldn't figure out how to make it work.
This is what I've so far:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();

Root<Employees> from = cq.from(Employees.class);
List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList();

if( filter.getDepartmentNumber() != null && !"".equals(filter.getDepartmentNumber()) ) {
    Join<DeptEmp, Employees> departments = from.join("deptEmpList");                   

    conditions.add(cb.equal(departments.get("deptEmpPK").get("deptNo"), filter.getDepartmentNumber()));
}

if( filter.getTitle() != null && !"".equals(filter.getTitle()) ) {
    Join<Titles, Employees> titles = from.join("titlesList");

    conditions.add(cb.equal(titles.get("deptNo"), filter.getTitle()));
}

cq = cq.select(from)
    .where(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[conditions.size()]))
    .groupBy(from.get("empNo"))
    .orderBy(cb.asc(from.get("empNo")));

TypedQuery<Employees> typedQuery = em.createQuery(cq);

typedQuery.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
typedQuery.setFirstResult(range[0]);

return typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Can someone help me?

(added from comments)

```
CREATE TABLE dept_emp (
    emp_no INT NOT NULL, 
    dept_no CHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
    from_date DATE NOT NULL, 
    to_date DATE NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees (emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments (dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,dept_no)
);
```

Comment: `<snide-remark>`I often wonder why the more verbose version is supposed to be better.`</snide-remark>`

Comment: @RickJames, I also tried converting it directly, without using the Criteria API, but it failed with an error that, as far as I could tell, seemed like a bug. It complains about the `HAVING MAX(b.toDate)`, saying that `Invalid query key [toDate] in expression`.

Comment: Hmmm... can you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE dept_emp`

Comment: `CREATE TABLE dept_emp (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    dept_no     CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE            NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no)  REFERENCES employees   (emp_no)  ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments (dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,dept_no)
);`

Comment: The SQL can be found [here](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db)

Comment: No.  Don't send us to Github and make me guess which file to look in.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this principle needs to be followed:

`employee` table seems to have two things in it:

- History of all comings and goings.
- Current state.

Split that into two tables.

Yes, it will involve extra code when inserting/updating the table(s), but it will simplify queries.

The query you started with would not need the `HAVING` and could easily hit the "current state" table.

Comment: It's a sample database, the all purpose is to adjust my programming to the schema, as if I were doing code for an existing database, that, general rule, cannot be easily changed.